# How big is the apple on the back of your MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

Bit of an offbeat question, I know: but are the apple logos on the back of Mac laptops all the same size? Has the size varied over time, or does it vary over the models that are currently available? I don't have easy access to an Apple Store so I can't go in and measure the logos by hand.

I'm trying to get some stickers made for an event, and as people seem to stick stickers on top laptops (and often over the Apple logo) I thought it would be a good idea to make the stickers slightly larger than the logo!

Answer (score 3):

On Macbook Pro 15 and Air 13, both mid-2012 : 47mm x 38mm